# Get coordinates of a print layout item in QGIS

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I would like to get the `x` value of a certain item from the print layout.

In fact, my others print layout items depend of the position of this item, and this is why I would like to be able to get those value from expression dialog.

In my case, into my print layout, a polyline `x y` depends of the position `x y` of an element image. When I move the image element, I would like the position of my polyline follows the image element position.

Is there a way to call an item using his ID from the expression dialog?

like : `x(geometry(item_ID))`

Comment: See https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#item-variables

Comment: thanks for documentation, but I'm not able to retrieve the X Y of an element using his ID :-( I may miss something.

Comment: You're right, I was assuming it was possible, but the PR was closed and not merged https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/36143

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define a new function returning X of a specified item.

```py
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args= 'auto' , group='Custom')
def GetItemX (LayoutName , ItemName, feature, parent):
    #variables
    layout_name = LayoutName
    item_name = ItemName

    #getting the layout
    manager = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager()
    layout = manager.layoutByName(layout_name)

    item = layout.itemById(item_name)
    item_position = item.positionWithUnits()
    item_x = item_position.x()

    return item_x
```

Usage:

```
GetItemX( @layout_name , 'Image 1')
```

Comment: it works, but the only issue I see it that it is a static result.
If I move the position of Image1, it doesn't change the X of the item. I have to load again the function. Is there any solution for this? thanks

Comment: Refresh the page `F5` after changing the position of item.